# Passing release variables between two agent phases

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm working with TFS on-premise.
My issue is that during a release I have two agent phases separated by a manual intervention.

In the first agent phase, I set a variable with:

```
Write-Verbose $("##vso[task.setvariable variable={0};]{1}" -f $variablename, $variable)
```

Problem is that in the second agent phase, this variable doesn't exist anymore, even if the same agent is used for the second release phase.

How may I pass a variable between two agent phases during the same release?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**There is no way to persist variables** (no matter powershell variables or VSTS user defined variables) **between two agent phases** (and environments) for now.

And there is a related issue [Variables set via logging commands are not persistent between agents](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4743), you can follow up.

The work around for now is define the variable again in next agent phase.

Comment: Are there any plans to get this in any future releases? If not, then what is the workaround? I almost tried everything.

Comment: @AhmedIG We write variables to a file in the drop folder, and read them back in the next phase. It's not pretty.

Answer (score 3):

You can share a variable between the agent phases by using the TFS Rest API and creating a new variable in the release.

You can create a helper module to facilitate this task.

1. [Get the release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) by using the environment variable `$Env:Release_ReleaseId`.
2. Add a NoteProperty, using `Add-Member`, to the variables hashtable of the release returned in step 1, where the name is your desired variable name and the value is a [ConfigurationVariableValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#configurationvariablevalue).
3. [Save the release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) with the added variable.

In order to use this approach, you would set the variable in your first agent. Then, in the second agent, you can simply read the TFS variable using the `$(VariableName)` semantic.

Comment: This blog also shows how to do it using this approach: https://nganmenegay.com/2019/04/25/azure-devops-pipelines-set-release-variables-using-release-rest-api-so-that-their-values-will-persist-across-stages/

Answer (score 1):

I've used the "Variable dehydration task" to write the value to my artifact folder in a build pipeline. I then read the json with inline-powershell. Currently, I'm reading it on every task in my release pipeline, which seems mental to me, but it sort of works. You ought to be able to set a global or env? variable and use that instead. Supposedly fixed in 2017, but I'm using 2015.

Comment: this seems to be the correct answer. do you know how to supply a custom json file name? because my release pipeline can't find the file that's created by the build pipeline.

Comment: can you see your json file in your build artifact?

Comment: no I don't see it. should it be available as an artifact?

Comment: the console output is:
Saving meta data for PROJECTVERSION

Name         Value  
----         -----  
PROJECTVERSION    1.2.3.4
meta-project.json        
created 


Finishing: variabledehydration

Comment: I was not aware that I had to publish the variables json as an artifact. I added a publish task and now it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is using Variablegroups to persist between pipelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Variables are reset between agent phases.

Comment: What if the variable value is dynamic and not fixed until the first "job" (phase) runs?   i.e. the unc path of the agent, for example.