# How do you set a variables in powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to set variables in a PowerShell so I can use them in custom conditions in a release definitions, so i can prevent phases from running is a VSTS variable is set to false or 0

Comment: `$variable_name = 'value'` for string data `$variable_name = value` for numeric data.

Comment: How does that work with VSTS variables? This needs to be use to the phase conditions.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/variable-groups?view=vsts. If this helps? It shows how you can create the scoped variables. Then link that variable group wherever you want to access.

Comment: It sounds to me like Ciaran O'Neill has the answer.

Comment: Mention VSTS/AzureDevops in the title. Setting variables in powershell is different from setting environment variables in VSTS using powershell.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use Write-Host with a special string format:

`Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=YourVSTSVariableName]$yourPowershellVariable"`

Comment: It may help others to note that the `YourVSTSVariableName` should appear in the format string as it appears in the pipeline variables tab. If var names have `.` in their name on that tab, then the `.` should be included in the format string. However, when accessing the value via `$env:YourVSTSVariableName` the `.` should be replaced with `_`.

Answer (score 3):

Setting variables in PowerShell itself is trivial, merely assign (= operator) to the variable:

```
$VarName = 42
```

But likely the question is looking for a way to set Environment variables which the (VSTS) application can 'see' and 'use' when it is called from PowerShell.

To assign to any session Environment variable prefix the name with "ENV" so it looks like this:

```
$Env:VarName = 4201
```

This will remain for the current PowerShell session or life of the console -- other sessions in other windows or run later will not see or be affected by such settings.

If you wish to have a persistent Environment variable then you must set that in the registry, either for the User (HKey_Local_User) or Computer (Hkey_Local_Machine).

These will get the environment settings from the registry (maybe be different that currently set in your process):

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('path',[EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('path',[EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
```

And the Set commands are similar but include the new value (e.g., variable 'Tools' is set to 'C:\':

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Tools', 'C:\', [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Tools', 'C:\', [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
```

There is also a "location" enumeration for "Process" (instead of User or Machine) but it is simpler to set this using the PowerShell $Env:VariableName shown above.

```
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Tools', 'C:\', [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize. I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Scenario-1: You want to set some variables outside of VSTS that are used by a Release Definition Inside VSTS

(a) I'd set those as environment variables on the host. You can call them from scripts that run on that host. 
(b) Set those variables in a separate Powershell script, then dot-source that script from a Powershell-task-script.

Scenario-2: You want to pass variable values from VSTS to a Powershell script

You're going to the **Build and Release** tab, selecting **Releases**, and then selecting the action **New Definition**. You're creating an empty process. You add a new artifact to the process. You eventually get to add a Powershell task (one of the utility tasks). For that task, you can select the script that gets run and the arguments you pass into it. Those arguments are parameters in the script. This like step 8/9 in the *Create a release definition* of the [CI/CD Hello world](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1?view=vsts#create-a-release-definition) article.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Even you can set variable value, but you can not use the modified variable value to prevent phases from running, since **variables can not persist between agent phases**.

And you can also refer the post [Passing release variables between two agent phases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891756/passing-release-variables-between-two-agent-phases).

And for the way to set variable in build, you can refer the document [Define and modify your variables in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/_shared/set-variables-in-scripts?view=vsts&tabs=powershell#set-in-script).