# Running a script in the Agentless Job

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I'm trying to set up an deployment pipeline in Azure DevOps for a web application. As part of this process, I need to issue a POST to an API in order to create a maintenance window with our monitoring service provider in order to maintain our SLA for the web application. In order to create the JSON payload for this API request, I need to have the exact date/time for both the start and end of the maintenance window.

So far, I have a PowerShell task setup for the Agent Job to run in order to obtain the times in the correct timezome (both the agent and the deployment agent are in the same facility/timezone).

I had to abbreviate some variable names due to a length limit I encountered for the script. But `$da` is just the duration argument for the length of the maintenance window.

```
Param([int]$da)
$df="yyyy-MM-dd"
$tf="HH:mm"
$start=(Get-Date).AddMinutes(1)
$end=$start.AddMinutes($da)
$startDate = $start.ToString($df)
$startTime=$start.ToString($tf)
$endDate=$end.ToString($df)
$endTime=$end.ToString($tf)
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=startDate]$startDate"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=startTime]$startTime"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=endDate]$endDate"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=endTime]$endTime"
```

This works fine, and I can verify that the variables are set correctly by using a new PowerShell task to run immediately after this one in the same job

```
Write-Host $env:startDate
Write-Host $env:startTime
Write-Host $env:endDate
Write-Host $env:endTime
```

But when I try to use these variables in a Invoke REST API task the Agentless Job, they appear empty. I'm issuing this to `postman-echo.com` for now to verify my payload.

```
{
    display_name:"$(Release.ReleaseName)",
    description:"Deployment requested by $(Release.RequestedFor)",
    start_date:"$(startDate)",
    start_time:"$(startTime)",
    end_date:"$(endDate)",
    end_time:"$(endTime)"
}
```

It appears that variables do not persist between Jobs. That being said, how do I go about accomplishing my goal considering that the PowerShell script task is not available within the Agentless Job, and the Invoke REST API task is only available in the Agentless Job? I need a way to run a script in the agentless jobto generate date/times for my deployment process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing release variables between two agent phases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891756/passing-release-variables-between-two-agent-phases)

Comment: That answers my first question, my second part is trying to find a way to run a script in the Agentless Phase so that I can build date/time variables in a specific timezone. But I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you just make it an agent phase and Invoke the REST API from a powershell script?

Comment: You can't run a script in an agentless phase. It's agentless. There's no place for a script to run.

Comment: @Matt Possibly, but I'm already running into a limit on the length of inline scripts, and it only seems to let me select PowerShell scripts that are part of the group of artifacts from the build output. Which I don't seem to have control over?

Comment: @NickAlbrecht, Possible you can create a repo for Deploy.Tools and commit your scripts there.  You can add multiple artifacts to a release pipeline, so just additionally include that repo, then you should be able to reference it.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to try that. I can't think of anything else to try after playing around with the options built into DevOps. I started along that line but haven't finished it yet. Once I've got some time and the holidays aren't upon us, I'll have to try and figure out how to create an empty build pipeline that pulls from a git repo, and includes the powershell file directly into the output artifacts so that it's available in the Release pipeline.